# Null value cannot be assigned - LINQ query question

Tags: linq

I have the following LINQ query:

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext(); 
var query = from contact in dc.Contacts
            select new
            {
                ContactId = contact.ContactId,
                LastName = contact.LastName,
                FirstName = contact.FirstName,
                Addresses = contact.Addresses,
                Phones = contact.Phones,
                DOB = contact.BirthDate,
                LastNote = contact.Notes.Max(n => n.Created), //this line causes the error
                Status = contact.ContactStatus.ContactStatusName,
                EmailAddress = contact.Emails
            };
```

The line where I get the maximum created date for the notes collection causes the following exception to be thrown:

> Exception: The null value cannot be assigned to a
>   member with type System.DateTime which
>   is a non-nullable value type.

How do I write the query to allow null values into the LastNote field?  The DOB field is defined as DateTime? and has not problem handling nulls.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Think I figured it out.

If I cast the maximum note value to a nullable DateTime it seems to eliminate the exception.  The following change worked for me:

```
LastNote = (Nullable<DateTime>)contact.Notes.Max(n => n.Created)
```

As others have pointed out, it can also be written using the shorthand notation for a nullable DateTime as follows:

```
LastNote = (DateTime?) contact.Notes.Max(n => n.Created)
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest that

Comment: That will work, though just FYI the shorthand of DateTime? is equivalent to Nullable<DateTime> (see Keltex's post)

Answer (score 9):

Rewrite that line as:

```
LastNote = (DateTime?) contact.Notes.Max(n => n.Created),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
LastNote = contact.Notes.Max(n => (DateTime?)n.Created)
```

Couldn't find this on the net so i hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

In VB is something like:

```
LastNote = CType(contact.Notes.Max(n => n.Created), Global.System.Nullable(Of Date))
```

I think...

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do that, or you could alter your database schema so that the column 'Created' does not allow nulls.

The scenario is arising because one of the rows comes back with a null value for Created.
If the db didn't allow nulls, the scenario would never occur.

Comment: You'd still get a null back from the call to Max if the contact didn't ever create any notes.

Comment: This suggestion is not valid. There is always the opportunity to have a null DateTime. I have worked with several db's now that have a DT field, such as 'closing_date'...no closing date has been applied yet, therefore, null.